# Docker permissions with base image for non-root user

Tags: docker, permissions, chown

I have a base image that does a couple of installments with root permission, then create a new user, change owner of the `WORKDIR` then switch to the user. The child image will inherit this image with `FROM` and run its Python task as user.

```
#base image

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /master

RUN adduser ...

RUN chown user:group -R .
USER user:group
```

These two images will have different `WORKDIR`, where the child image's `WORKDIR` is the sub directory of the base image, created during image build.

```
#child image

FROM base-image
WORKDIR /master/worker

...

RUN pip install -e .
```

When building the child image, the last pip command got an error, it can not create new files because lack of permission

```
error: could not create 'python_project.egg-info': Permission denied
```

Apparently, the command `chown` in base image only grant permission to user for base image `WORKDIR`, not including newly created sub-directory in the child image's `WORKDIR`.

If I create `master/worker` during base image build then change owner, the child image works, because the user is now owner of both  `/master` and `/master/worker`

```
#base image

...

MKDIR worker
RUN chown user:group -R .
USER user:group
```

But I prefer not to do this, since there might be more different `WORKDIR` created from other child images.

Is there any way I can grant permission to sub-directory in child image from the base image (that does not exist yet in there)? The `chown -R` flag doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just simply create the subfolder before setting it as `WORKDIR` in child image

```
RUN mkdir worker
WORKDIR /master/worker
```